# Can I create a Chocolatey package for an EXE that isn't an installer?

Tags: package, chocolatey

I have an open source tool that I want to make available from Chocolatey.  Right now the application is just an EXE and config file (and a couple extra dlls).  Can I build a package for just these files or do I need to create an installer first?  If I can do it without the installer, is there an example of this?  If using a MSI is a better practice, I can create one.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Resounding yes! On the community package repo you see an overwhelming amount of installer packages, but packages w/runtime binaries are much more "true" packages. This is also mentioned at https://chocolatey.org/docs (search for "fantastically").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a package just for those files without creating an installer first.
Those kind of packages are usually referred to as portable packages (packages that do not require administrative privileges to install).

Basically all you need to do, is add the files inside the package, create a VERIFICATION.txt file which details how moderators can verify the binaries (remember to also include that you're the software author), and a LICENSE.txt (can be named differently) with the license of the software.

An example of such a package would be my own package for electrum-ltc.portable:
https://chocolatey.org/packages/electrum-ltc.portable

Comment: You don't need to add .portable to the name when you create the package though. It's typically not recommended to add .install/.portable unless a piece of software has both.

Comment: Here's another example - https://chocolatey.org/packages/ARMClient. Also the updated NUnit packages. PowerShell scripts are completely optional, you may also find this helpful (applies to runtime binaries in packages as well): https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1303#issuecomment-303804561 (this comment by itself).

Comment: Thanks for the tips and examples!  I have this working now and just finishing up some command line args.  I'll hopefully be submitting my package today.